# Android Contributing to Open Source Projects with the gradle dependency

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

So I am starting to work on some open source libraries that is out there, mainly I have found bugs with the library using my specific project. As far as I know the Gradle library dependency is cached somewhere and not accessible.

What I would like to do is be able to create a branch for the fix and test in my project. Is there efficient way of doing this or do I need to comment out my gradle dependency and do a manual import of the library and do the fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that project is available on GitHub? You have 2 options then:

- Open a issue at the project and describe your problems. Maybe the author will fix them himself
- Fork the Project. You can work on your own on it then and make a Pull Request later if you want to.

You can of course download the source code and modify it yourself locally too, but that's not the purpose of Open Source Projects I think :)

Comment: My assumption for open source projects was that they should work like the git flow http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/why-arent-you-using-git-flow/ and you create a branch test your branch (what i am trying to do) and then submit a pull request for the fix. The whole testing piece is what I would like to streamline instead of manual importing of the branch that I want to work on to test with my project.

Comment: You can't just create a branch on a project you doesn't own. Unless you are a Cotributor of that Project and the owner allows you to do so of course.
If that would be allowed eveybody could just do what he wants with the project.